# What attacks does IPSec protect against?

Tags: ipsec

As in the title, what attacks does IPSec protect against?

Comment: have you done any research on the question at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, Internet Protocol security (IPSec) is a framework of open standards for helping to ensure private, secure communications over Internet Protocol (IP) networks through the use of cryptographic security services. It is  integrated at the Internet layer (layer 3), it provides security for almost all protocols in the TCP/IP suite (through different policies) and it can help against:

- Network-based attacks from untrusted computers, attacks that can result in    the denial-of-service of applications, services, or the network
- Data corruption
- Data theft
- User-credential theft
- Administrative control of servers, other computers, and the network
- Block untrusted communications

Most of these threats occur throught some sort of Man in The Middle attack. Even if an attack like that is successful, using IPSec will keep the data encrypted and make sure they all reached their destination without any alterations on their way.